# ConTeXt : wrapfigure interacts with marginrule

Tags: floats, context

While working with ConTeXt, I bumped into the problem described in the following MWE :

```
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=4cm]
\starttext

\startmarginrule[8]
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\startmarginrule
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\placefigure[here,none,right]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
\input knuth

\startmarginrule[8]
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\startmarginrule
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\stoptext
```

[image]

The problem also appear with `\placefigure[left]`, but not with `\placefigure[center]`. Can anyone explain it and provide a workaround please ?

Comment: I'm using ConTeXt shipped with TL 2016 and for me [weird things are happening](http://i.stack.imgur.com/trKK9.png), so it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in [`anch-bar.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/anch-bar.mkiv). I have posted a bugfix on [ntg-context](https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg83010.html) and it has been merged in the beta.

```
*** /opt/context-minimals/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/anch-bar.mkiv 2016-08-28 16:55:00.000000000 -0400
--- anch-bar.mkiv   2016-08-28 16:52:47.000000000 -0400
***************
*** 111,118 ****
         \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
       \fi
     \else
       \ifnum\m_level=\plusone
-        \scratchdimen\sidebarparameter\c!leftmargindistance\relax
         \ifdim\scratchdimen=\zeropoint
           \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
         \else
--- 111,118 ----
         \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
       \fi
     \else
+      \scratchdimen\sidebarparameter\c!leftmargindistance\relax
       \ifnum\m_level=\plusone
         \ifdim\scratchdimen=\zeropoint
           \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
         \else
```

If you are using an older version, you can copy the adapted definition of `\anch_sidebars_start` in your current file:

```
\unprotect
\def\anch_sidebars_start[#1][#2]%
  {\bgroup
   \dontleavehmode
   \advance\c_anch_sidebars_level\plusone
   \global\advance\c_anch_sidebars_n\plusone
   \c_anch_sidebars_current\c_anch_sidebars_n\relax % relax needed
   \doifelseassignment{#1}
     {\edef\currentsidebar{\the\c_anch_sidebars_level}%
      \checksidebarparent
      \setupcurrentsidebar[#1]}
     {\def\currentsidebar{#1}%
      \setupcurrentsidebar[#2]}%
   \scratchdistance\sidebarparameter\c!distance\relax
   \edef\m_level{\sidebarparameter\c!level}%
   \ifx\m_level\empty
     \ifnum\c_anch_sidebars_level=\plusone
       \scratchdimen\sidebarparameter\c!leftmargindistance\relax
       \ifdim\scratchdimen=\zeropoint
         \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
       \else
         \d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdimen
       \fi
     \else
       \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
     \fi
   \else
     \scratchdimen\sidebarparameter\c!leftmargindistance\relax
     \ifnum\m_level=\plusone
       \ifdim\scratchdimen=\zeropoint
         \advance\d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdistance\relax
       \else
         \d_anch_sidebars_distance\scratchdimen
       \fi
     \else
       \d_anch_sidebars_distance\dimexpr\scratchdimen+\numexpr\m_level-\plusone\relax\dimexpr\scratchdistance\relax\relax
     \fi
   \fi
   \startpositionoverlay{\v!text-1}%
     \normalexpanded{\setMPpositiongraphicrange % maybe expand in definition
       {b:sidebar:\the\c_anch_sidebars_n}%
       {e:sidebar:\the\c_anch_sidebars_n}%
       {mpos:sidebar}%
       {self=sidebar:\the\c_anch_sidebars_n,
        linewidth=\sidebarparameter\c!rulethickness,
        linecolor=\sidebarparameter\c!rulecolor,
        alternative=\sidebarparameter\c!alternative,
        topoffset=\the\dimexpr\sidebarparameter\c!topoffset,
        bottomoffset=\the\dimexpr\sidebarparameter\c!bottomoffset,
        distance=\the\d_anch_sidebars_distance}%
     }%
   \stoppositionoverlay
   \bpos{sidebar:\the\c_anch_sidebars_current}%
   \ignorespaces}
\protect

\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=4cm]

\starttext

\startmarginrule[8]
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\startmarginrule
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\placefigure[here,none,right]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
\input knuth

\startmarginrule[8]
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\startmarginrule
  Test
\stopmarginrule

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: That's great ! I hope it will quickly be integrated to the main distribution. Thank you for your work here.